# Is the complex function $f(z)=e^{-z^{-4}}$ analytic at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the complex function $$f(z)=\begin{cases}
e^{-z^{-4}} & z\ne0\\
0 & z=0
\end{cases}$$ analytic at $z=0$ ?

I am able to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied.

Comment: The function is **not** continuous at zero (if you are considering it defined on $\mathbb C$, as you seem to be doing).

Comment: One way to see $f(z)$ is not continuous at $0$ is approach the origin along the diagonals $\Re z = \pm \Im z$.

Comment: "I am able to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied." Then there must be some mistakes in your computations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are using thermonuclear weapons to conclude...

The function is not even continuous at zero. For example, there exists in $\mathbb C$ a sequence $(w_n)_{n\geq0}$ such that $w_n\to\infty$ and $\exp w_n^4=1$ for all $n\geq0$. It follows that $1/w_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $f(1/w_n)=\exp(-(1/w_n)^{-4})=1$ for all $n$, and this together with $f(0)=0$ imply that $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: You can take $w_n$ to be any of the fourth roots of $2\pi n i$, for example.

Comment: Thank you for making it so simple !

Comment: Isn't it an essential singularity?

Comment: @WilsonofGordon. Yes. For any $r\in \Bbb R^+$  let $S(r)= \{-z^{-4}: 0<|z|<r\}$ and $T(r)=  \{z+2\pi i n: z\in S(r)\land n\in \Bbb Z\}.$ Then $S(r)=\{z: |z|>r^4\}$ so $T(r)=\Bbb C.$ So $\{e^z: z\in S(r)\}= \{e^z:z\in T(r)\}=\{e^z:z\ne 0\}=\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}.$

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(z)$ thus defined has a Laurent series expansion
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} z^{-4n} $$
around $z=0$ with an infinite principal part (i.e. with infinitely many non-zero coefficients in front of the negative powers of $z$).

Thus $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$, and by the Casoratti-Weierstraß theorem, there is no way to define $f(0)$ so that $f(z)$ be continuous at $z=0$. In fact, we have 
$$ |f(z)| = e^{-\Re(z^{-4})} = \exp\left(\frac{-x^4+6x^2y^2-y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^4}\right) \quad \text{for} \quad z = x +iy \neq 0.$$
Restricting $z$ to the line $y = tx$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we observe that
$$ \lim_{x\to0}|f(x+itx)| = \lim_{x\to 0}\,\exp\left(\frac{-1+6t^2-t^4}{x^4(1+t^2)^4}\right)\tag{1}\label{limit}$$
is not independent of $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, we can factor the biquadratic polynomial $-1+6t^2-t^4$ as
$$-\big((t^2-3)^2 - 8\big) = -\big(t^2-(\sqrt{2}-1)^2\big)\big(t^2-(\sqrt{2}+1)^2\big) = -(t+\sqrt{2}+1)(t+\sqrt{2}-1)(t-\sqrt{2}+1)(t-\sqrt{2}-1),$$
whence we deduce that the limit \eqref{limit} equals either $1$ (for $t = \pm\sqrt{2}\pm1$), or $\infty$ (whenever $|t+\sqrt{2}| < 1$ or $|t-\sqrt{2}|<1$), or $0$ (otherwise). Therefore, we conclude that $\lim_{z\to0}|f(z)|$ does not exist. Hence, the limit $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ does not exist either, and thus, $f(z)$ cannot be analytic at $z=0$.

**Edit:** I would like to thank Abhishek Verma for pointing out an error in the original solution: the denominator appearing in the expression for $|f(z)|$ was incorrectly calculated as $(x^2+y^2)^2$, instead of $(x^2+y^2)^4$.

Answer (score -1):

I would say no, because every derivative is $0$ at $0$, (due to expontential growth), see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: One should better say that all derivatives of the *restriction* of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$ vanish at $x=0$, as $f$ itself is not differentiable at $z=0$.

Answer (score -4):

Since you already know the function is continuous, we can conclude directly that it is analytic from Riemann's theorem (about removable singularity).

Comment: I am not sure why I keep getting -1 here...The asker previously claimed that the function is continuous (before it was edited out). I am pointing out the simple fact that if you have a function that is already analytic everywhere except one point, and is continuous at that point, then it clearly is just a removable singularity.

Comment: Continuous functions aren't necessarily analytic (and this function is *not* continuous at $0$).

Comment: @user61527: please take a look at Riemann's removable singularity theorem. And the question before being edited was that it is a continuous function.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that a holomorphic function that's bounded near a singularity can be extended. I'm not sure what you're saying about the relevance of the theorem about removable singularities here: $0$ is, in fact, an essential singularity of this function, since there are infinitely many non-zero terms in the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $0$. (Also, as far as I see, the only edits about the definition of the function were cosmetic.)

Comment: @user61527: the question was previously (at the moment I gave the answer) stated to be continuous, and I simply recognize that as an obvious application of the theorem. The fact that the function have essential singularity here is the mistake on the asker's part, and it seems more reasonable to assume that the asker got the function wrong rather than the continuity wrong. In any case, it is clear that the asker did not notice that the theorem is applicable once continuity is known, which is why I gave this answer.

Comment: In that case, you might want to add a note to your answer explaining that it was based on the faulty assumption of the OP.